# How can you continue to next line in python after catching an exception?

Tags: python, error-handling

I am semi new to python and am working with some APIs, currently I am making a ton of API calls within a loop, some of which may produces errors. The thing is that I want the iteration of the current loop to continue to the next line even when an error is caught.

My code simplified looks like this:

```
while x = 0

    try:

        API CALL 1
        API CALL 2
        API CALL 3
        API CALL 4

    except:

        print("an input error was made")
```

The problem essentially is that I have hundreds of API calls and want avoid putting an individual try except block on each of them. If API CALL 2 fails, I still want to run API CALL 3 for this iteration. I have tried toying around with pass and continue but whenever an error is caught it takes me right back to the top of the loop, whereas I want to catch the error and then move onto the next line.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: why not use a `while` loop in which you'd `try` and `except` every API call? (with `pass` in the `except` section)

Comment: There are hundreds of calls which is why I was looking for another solution

Comment: but the while loop would handle them all - that is the concept of loops